# Creating Android ConstraintLayout and Guidelines in code

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

How do you create ConstraintLayouts and Guidelines programmatically? I've tried the below code to create a simple layout that anchors a view to the middle of the screen using a Guideline, but it renders the red 'v' view on the left side of the screen (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bIos.png))

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ConstraintLayout cl = new ConstraintLayout(this);
        cl.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        setContentView(cl);

        Guideline gl = new Guideline(this);
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams gllp = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 500);
        gllp.guidePercent = 0.5f;
        gllp.orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL;
        gl.setLayoutParams(gllp);
        gl.setId(View.generateViewId());
        cl.addView(gl);

        View v = new View(this);
        v.setId(View.generateViewId());
        v.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF0000);
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(50, 500);
        lp.rightToRight = gl.getId();
        v.setLayoutParams(lp);
        cl.addView(v);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug that is now fixed in beta4. Note that you have to call lp.validate() after setting up ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams in code. More details at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=227039.

Answer (score 2):

Which version of `ConstraintLayout` are you using? Trying your example with beta 3, I get the correct behavior:

[image]

**edit** -- I was incorrect, and beta 4 has the fix for this issue.

In addition, for programmatically creating layout params with ConstraintLayout, you should call the validate() function on ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams before setting it to the view.

Comment: I'm also using beta3. This is very strange. I did get the error at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=227030 when I installed, but the install succeeds even though you get an error. I checked the md5 of the actual constraint-layout-1.0.0-beta3.aar file and it has the correct md5 I think (0b98641b30b62b65adbeba29d90d1107) so it seems to really be beta3.

Comment: I just had my coworker install constraint-layout (which succeeded without errors) and try this and he gets the same broken behavior that I do. Using beta3.

Comment: I get the correct behavior with beta1. So it looks like this was a regression in beta2. I've confirmed this on my machine and my coworker's machine. Tested on nexus 6 with android 5, and on emulator with android 5, 6, and 7 (same behavior on all).

Comment: Also note that the bug that I filed that has a slightly more advanced example than this is *not* working in beta1-3 (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=227039).